# command line Detect network adapter name and change IP

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I just know ethernet card description and I want to find ethernet name and adjust IP address. I tried this:

```
 FOR /F "tokens=4,* delims= " %%a in ('wmic nic get name ^, netconnectionid ^|find  "Gigabit"') do set localIp=%%b
echo %localIp%" & 
netsh interface ip set address name=%interfaceName% static 192.168.2.5
pause
```

this finds my network adapter name but couldn't set IP address.

Thereafter I tried this:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%F in ('wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and AdapterTypeId=0" get NetConnectionID /format:list') do set InterFaceName=%%F
echo %interfaceName% & 
netsh interface ip set address name=%interfaceName% static 192.168.5.5
pause
```

this also finds the name but If the name has just one word, it works but if the name contains a space, it couldn't change IP. There is just a message `Invalid source parameter <"second word">`

Comment: Also post the output of running the command.

Comment: Use doublequotes, `Name="%interfaceName%"`!

Comment: Thank you @Compo solved with doublequotes